# Preorder on a pseudo-topological space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose you have a pseudo-topological space $(X,p)$, where $p$ is a binary relation from the set of all ultrafilters of $X$ to the points of $x$, called 'convergence'.

What does it mean for this relation $p$ to be a a pre-order? I know a pre-order is a relation that is reflexive and transitive, but I am not sure how to translate this into the 'convergence' relation, $p$.

Apparently, reflexive here means that the principle ultra-filter, $F_x = \{A\subseteq X: x\in A\}$ converges to its point i.e. $F_x \rightarrow x$ for all $x\in X$.

Also how does transitive work here? Would it be if $F\rightarrow x$ and $\bar{F} \rightarrow x,\bar{F} \rightarrow y$ then also ${F}\rightarrow y$?

The motivation behind all of this is to make some restrictions on $p$ so that we get a topological space from the pseudo-topological one.

I am highly confused and would appreciate if someone could clarify what is happening here, or point me to references where this is explained.

Comment: Have you seen $p$ referred to as a preorder in some context?  This doesn't make any sense taken literally, since the domain and codomain of $p$ are different sets.

Comment: In the context of $(T,V)$-categories it makes sense to talk about transitive convergence relations(here $T$ is monad and $V$ a quantale). Very roughly speaking, it is possible to define an alternative composition $\ast$ in the Kleisli category such that "transitivity makes sence";  that is, for a convergence relation $c$ transitivity is expressed by $c\ast c\leq c$. According to the usual definitions in this setting, a pseudo-topological space equipped with a transitive convergence relation is a topological space.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a pre-order by:

$x \le y$ iff every ultrafilter that converges to $x$ (under $p$) also converges to $y$.

This is clearly transitive and reflexive ($x \le x$ is trivial), by definition almost. The idempotence axiom (that fixed ultrafilters converge) is not even needed here.